# Set x and y range in bar plot in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

How to set `x` and `y` range in a bar plot. My plot currently likes the following (in python):

```
x = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
y = [3,5,76,8,96,1]
data = [go.Bar(
    x=x,
    y=y
)]
layout = {
   'xaxis': {'title': 'Query Duration'},
   'yaxis': {'title': 'Proportion (%)'},
   'barmode': 'relative'
}
```

But as I tested, I couldn't send `range` to the `data` or `layout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the layout like so. The `range` property of `xaxis` or `yaxis` can be used for this.

> **range (array)** 
>  Sets the range of this axis. If the axis type is "log", then you must take the log of your desired range (e.g. to
>   set the range from 1 to 100, set the range from 0 to 2). If the axis 
>   type is "date", it should be date strings, like date data, though Date
>   objects and unix milliseconds will be accepted and converted to
>   strings. If the axis type is "category", it should be numbers, using
>   the scale where each category is assigned a serial number from zero in
>   the order it appears. Each object has one or more of the keys listed
>   below.

Check the [`official documentation`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/) also.

```
x = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
y = [3,5,76,8,96,1]
data = [go.Bar(
    x=x,
    y=y
)]
layout = {
   'xaxis': {'title': 'Query Duration', 'range': [1, 10]},
   'yaxis': {'title': 'Proportion (%)'}, 'range': [1, 100]},
   'barmode': 'relative'
}
```